# How to upload local csv to bigquery

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am referring [tylertreat-BigQuery-Python](https://github.com/tylertreat/BigQuery-Python) library to upload csv to BigQuery. To upload data to GBQ it needs Google Cloud Storage path but I want to upload my local csv. Is there a way to upload local csv instead of GS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use `media upload` mechanism.

- API documentation: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-post-request
- Python API: https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/blob/master/googleapiclient/http.py#L381